# docx4j traversalutil finds no TextElements in the Paragraph node

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, docx4j

**Edit:** I know what a NullPointerException is, the problem is, that docx4j don't finds any elements in the Paragraph Node.

I'm trying to get the first element of the Text Class in a paragraph.

```
ClassFinder finder = new ClassFinder(P.class);
    new TraversalUtil(model.getWordMLPackage().getMainDocumentPart(),
            finder);
    finder.results.stream().forEach(
            elem -> {

                ClassFinder findfirsttext = new ClassFinder(Text.class);
                new TraversalUtil(elem, findfirsttext);
                Text tt=((Text)findfirsttext.results.get(0));
                System.out.println("asdf"+tt.getValue());

            });
```

but

```
                    Text tt=((Text)findfirsttext.results.get(0));
```

always results in a NullPointerException. Because the util doesn't find text elements in the Paragraph.

Since I'm parsing a valid document every Paragraph should contain at least one Text element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.docx4j/docx4j/3.0.1/org/docx4j/finders/ClassFinder.java), you dont have any element in arrayList and you are trying to getValue from null and hence end up in NullPointerException.

Comment: As per this answer, your assumption that a paragraph contains at least one text element is incorrect.